# in ruby how to remove the last part of ip address

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby.

I have an ip address and I need the strip the last part of the ip address.

e.g.

208.68.38.12 becomes 208.68.38

How do I do that in ruby?

Answer (score 5):

Can be done this way:

```
ip = "208.68.38.12"
ip.split(".")[0...-1].join(".")
#=> "208.68.38"
```

If you go step by step, the above used line of code is quite self-explanatory. Here:

```
ip.split(".") # splitting string on `.` so we have an Array
#=> ["208", "68", "38", "12"]
ip.split(".")[0...-1] # taking 0th to n-1 th element of Array (-1 represents last element when size is unknown)
#=> ["208", "68", "38"]
ip.split(".")[0...-1].join(".") # finally joining the Array over `.`
#=> "208.68.38"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another version:

```
ip = "208.68.38.12"
ip[0...ip.rindex('.')] # => "208.68.38"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
"208.68.38.12".split('.')[0,3].join('.') #=> "208.68.38"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ip = '208.68.38.12'
ip[/.*(?=\.\d+\z)/]
#⇒ "208.68.38"
```

Here we use [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and positive lookahead in regular expression to omit last dot and following numbers in the result.

BTW, there are gems all around to deal with IPs, e. g.: https://github.com/deploy2/ruby-ip

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can rely on a well-formed IPv4 address:

```
ip.sub(/\.[^.]*\z/, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ip = ip.split('.')[0..-2].join('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way, in my opinion:

```
"208.68.38.12"[/(\.?\d+){3}/]
```